# how to dynamically change the message in popup in React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I can not seem to figure out how to refresh the popup child component when the message is changed. This is part of my parent element code:

```
dataFetching = (props) => {         
            fetch('https://desolate-harbor-55159.herokuapp.com/signin', {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email: this.state.signInEmail,
                password: this.state.signInPassword
            })
        }).then(response => response.json())
                .then(user => {
                    if (user.email === this.state.signInEmail) {
                        this.props.loadUser(user)
                        this.props.onRouteChange('home') 
                    } else {
                        return (                                                                
                            this.changemessage('wrong credentials')                     
                        )
                    }                       
                })      
}

changemessage = (message) => {
    this.setState({popupmessage: message})
}

render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.popupstate
                    ? <Popup popupmessage={this.state.popupmessage} togglePopup={this.togglePopup}/>
```

and this is the `Popup` child element code:

```
class Popup extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            togglepopup: this.props.tooglePopup,
            popupmessage: this.props.popupmessage
        }
    }

    tooglePopup = (value) => {
        this.props.togglePopup(false)
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div className='popup-box center w-20 br3 mt5 b--green b--solid' onClick={this.tooglePopup} >
                { <div className='tc'>
                        <h1>
                            {this.state.popupmessage}
                        </h1>
                        <p>click me</p>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I am new to this and I am already getting lost here....

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine for you

```
class Popup extends React.Component {

render () {
    return (
        <div className='popup-box center w-20 br3 mt5 b--green b--solid' onClick={() => this.props.tooglePopup()} >
            { <div className='tc'>
                    <h1>
                        {this.props.popupmessage}
                    </h1>
                    <p>click me</p>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

Comment: this did not change the text inside my Popup window to 'wrong credentials' after fetch data validation. It still stays on 'Loading...'I only see the 400 bad request in the console but my Popup did not update

Comment: What I need here is to dynamically update the text inside the Popup once I declare the ``this.setState({popupmessage: message})``  here in the return of the ``dataFetching`` function

Answer (score 0):

I got it. I had change few things. I replaced

```
tooglePopup = (value) => {
        this.props.togglePopup(false)
    }
```

with

```
handleClick = () => {
       this.props.toggle();
    };
```

and added this to my Popup element

```
render () {
        return (
            <div className='popup-box center w-20 br3 mt5 b--green b--solid' onClick={this.handleClick} >
                { <div className='tc'>
                        <h2>
                            {this.props.message}
                        </h2>
                        <p>click me</p>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
```

and in the parent element I had to change the way it displays the popup, I have added this to the beginning of the render with message to be passed like this:

```
render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className='center mt4'>        
                     {this.state.popupstate ? <Popup className='center w-100 flex' toggle={this.togglePop} message={this.state.popupmessage}/> : null}      
                </div>
```